# PHP redirect fails if <html> tag is specified

Tags: php, html, redirect

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Location: https://www.google.com/', true, 302);
    exit();
    }
?>
<form method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /><br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The form works as expected if the "html" and "body" tags are removed. The presence of either one of them causes failure. This occurs on one hosting site; however I can run it on another host without any problems.

Are there any settings in php.ini that could cause this behavior?

When the code runs with the "html" or "body" tags, this error is displayed:
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /webroot/m/o/montc001/primary/www/test.php:3) in /webroot/m/o/montc001/primary/www/test.php on line 7

The site that fails, also has Wordpress installed. The WP site is being replaced by a new implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header function has to be at the top and called before any html is printed out.

From the php.net documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) :

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

So your code should be something like:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        header('Location: https://www.google.com/', true, 302);
    exit();
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' /><br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```